# how to speed up scene._render_pygame_def_update() in python

Tags: python, math, 3d

im trying to make a 3d renderer but i can only get at most 20fps on idle.
i tried using @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None) on project_and_rotate() and got it up to 40fps on idle.
is there any way i could make this any faster
im using a long math formula i found a few month ago but it seems to be to slow for the map in projected_des

```
from math import *
import pygame
import numpy
from functools import lru_cache





@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def project_and_rotate(x, y, z,rotx,roty,rotz,posx,posy,posz,cx,cy,cz,scale,render_distance):
            x,y,z=x-posx,y-posy,z-posz
            if abs(x)>render_distance or abs(z)>render_distance:return None
            
            px = (((x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * cos(roty) - z * sin(roty)) * (315 / ((((z * cos(roty) + (x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * sin(roty)) * cos(rotx) + (y * cos(rotz) + x * sin(rotz)) * sin(rotx)) + 5) + cz))) * scale + cx
            py = (((y * cos(rotz) + x * sin(rotz)) * cos(rotx) - (z * cos(roty) + (x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * sin(roty)) * sin(rotx)) * (315 / ((((z * cos(roty) + (x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * sin(roty)) * cos(rotx) + (y * cos(rotz) + x * sin(rotz)) * sin(rotx)) + 5) + cz))) * scale + cy
            
            return [round(px),round(py)]




    
class coordinate:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z
        
class verticies_structure:
    def __init__(self):
        self._verts=[]
    def add_vert(self,x,y,z):
        self._verts.append(coordinate(x,y,z))
    def get_coords(self,indexes):
        return self._verts[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]
        
class camera:
    def __init__(self,w,h,render_distance,fov=45):
        self.fov=360-fov
        self.w=w
        self.h=h
        self.x=0
        self.rx=0
        self.cx=0
        self.y=0
        self.ry=0
        self.cy=0
        self.z=0
        self.rz=0
        self.cz=0
        self.render_distance=render_distance
        
def false(f,value):
    if value==f:
        value=f+0.01
    return value
    
def inf360(value):
    if value>359:value=0
    if value<0:value=359
    return value
        
        
class mesh(object):
    def __init__(self,file_obj,cam):
        self.cam=cam
        self.verts=verticies_structure()
        self.source=file_obj
        self.read_object_file()
        
        self.verts=verticies_structure()
        
        size=100
        for x in range(size):
            for z in range(size):
                self.verts.add_vert(x-size//2,0,z-size//2)
        
        
        self.w2s_vect=numpy.vectorize(self.w2s)
        self.array_verts=numpy.array(self.verts._verts)
                
                
    def w2s(self,coord):
        cam=self.cam
        return project_and_rotate(coord.x,coord.y,coord.z,cam.ry,cam.rx,cam.rz,cam.x,cam.y,cam.z,cam.cx,cam.cy,cam.cz,10,cam.render_distance)
        


        
    def projected_des(self,cam):
        #return self.w2s_vect(self.array_verts).tolist()
            
        return map( lambda coord:project_and_rotate(coord.x,coord.y,coord.z,cam.ry,cam.rx,cam.rz,cam.x,cam.y,cam.z,cam.cx,cam.cy,cam.cz,10,cam.render_distance),self.verts.get_coords([0,-1]))    
        
    def read_object_file(self):
        self.verts=verticies_structure()        
        import re
        reComp = re.compile("(?<=^)(v |vn |vt |f )(.*)(?=$)", re.MULTILINE)
        with open(self.source) as f:
            data = [txt.group() for txt in reComp.finditer(f.read())]
        v_arr, vn_arr, vt_arr, f_arr = [], [], [], []
        for line in data:
            tokens = line.split(' ')
            if tokens[0] == 'v':
                v_arr.append([float(c) for c in tokens[1:]])
            elif tokens[0] == 'vn':
                vn_arr.append([float(c) for c in tokens[1:]])
            elif tokens[0] == 'vt':
                vn_arr.append([float(c) for c in tokens[1:]])
            elif tokens[0] == 'f':
                f_arr.append([[int(i) if len(i) else 0 for i in c.split('/')] for c in tokens[1:]])
        vertices, normals = [], []
        for face in f_arr:
            for tp in face:
                self.verts.add_vert(*v_arr[tp[0]-1])
        
        self.array_verts=numpy.array(self.verts._verts)
class draw:
    class frame:
        class pygame_uitl:
            def grid(rowx,rowy,px,color=(255,255,255)):
                display=pygame.display.get_surface()
                for r in range(rowx):
                    r+=1
                    pygame.draw.line(display,color,(0,(display.get_height()/(rowx+1))*r),(display.get_width(),(display.get_height()/(rowx+1))*r),px)
                for r in range(rowy):
                    r+=1
                    pygame.draw.line(display,color,((display.get_width()/(rowy+1))*r,0),((display.get_width()/(rowy+1))*r,display.get_height()),px)
  

class system:                    
    class pygame_util:
        def get_orientation():
            inf=pygame.display.Info()
            w,h=inf.current_w,inf.current_h
            if w>h:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0




class Drivers:
    class Pygame:
        DEFAULT="PG-default"
        SDL2="PG-sdl2"
    
class master:
    class scene:
        def __init__(self,wh:list,display_driver:str,render_distance:int,fps:int):
            self._model={
                "class 1":[],
                "class 2":[],
                "class 3":[],
                "class 4":[]}
            self._fps=fps
            self._window_wh=wh
            self._driver=display_driver
            self._camera=camera(*wh,render_distance)
            self._mode="mesh"
            self._super_ls=0
            
            if display_driver==Drivers.Pygame.DEFAULT:
                self._render_pygame_def_setup()
            
        def add_model(self,file):
            model=mesh(file,self._camera)
            vertexes=len(model.verts._verts)
            if vertexes>100:
                self._model["class 4"].append(model)
            elif vertexes>50:
                self._model["class 3"].append(model)
            elif vertexes>25:
                self._model["class 2"].append(model)
            else:
                self._model["class 1"].append(model)
        def regulate_camera(self):
            self._camera.rx,self._camera.ry,self._camera.rz=false(0,self._camera.rx),false(0,self._camera.ry),false(0,self._camera.rz)
            self._camera.cx,self._camera.cy,self._camera.cz=false(0,self._camera.cx),false(0,self._camera.cy),false(0,self._camera.cz)  
        def correct_camera(self,orient=1):
            self._orient=orient
            if orient:
                self._camera.cx=self._window_wh[1]//2
                self._camera.cy=self._window_wh[0]
                self._camera.ry=0.4
            else:
                self._camera.cx=self._window_wh[0]//2
                self._camera.cy=self._window_wh[1]
                self._camera.ry=0.2
                
        def auto_render_distance(self):
            if self._driver==Drivers.Pygame.DEFAULT:
                if self._pygame_clock.get_fps()+5>self._fps:
                    self._camera.render_distance+=1
                else:
                    self._camera.render_distance-=1

        def landscape_super(self):
            self._super_ls=1
            self._lss_hdri_file_jpg_surf=pygame.Surface([self._window_wh[0],self._window_wh[1]//2.01])
            self._lss_hdri_file_jpg_surf.fill((200,220,255))
            
        def _render_pygame_def_setup(self):
            self._pygame_clock=pygame.time.Clock()
            self._pygame_screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self._camera.w,self._camera.h),pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.HWACCEL|pygame.HWSURFACE)
            
        def _render_pygame_def_update(self):
                self._pygame_screen.fill((0,70,0))
                self.regulate_camera()

                for idx,vclass in self._model.items():
                    for model in vclass: 
                        for point in model.projected_des(self._camera):
                            if point!=None:
                                try:self._pygame_screen.set_at(point,(255,255,255))
                                except:pass



                
                if self._super_ls:
                    self._pygame_screen.blit(self._lss_hdri_file_jpg_surf,(0,0))     
        
        def _render_pygame_def_finish(self):
                pygame.display.flip()
                self._pygame_clock.tick(self._fps)
                
                










   
                
scene=master.scene([2176,1080],Drivers.Pygame.DEFAULT,render_distance=25,fps=60)

scene.add_model("cube.obj")
scene.correct_camera(0)
scene.landscape_super()


#make the sky mapped to edge of render
pygame.font.init()
while 1:
    rx,ry=pygame.mouse.get_rel()
    scene._camera.rx+=rx/200
    
    scene._render_pygame_def_update()
    
    #scene.auto_render_distance()
    
    scene._pygame_screen.blit(pygame.font.SysFont(None,60).render(str(scene._pygame_clock.get_fps()),None,(255,0,0)),(0,0))
    
    scene._render_pygame_def_finish()
```

Comment: open & close a block code with triple ` (start at a new line); inline code with a single `. Please edit

Comment: you still need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75012280/edit) it with your code again, the current code has a lot of artifacts that make it unusable because of your editor, open your application using **notepad** and `ctrl +A` to select all then `ctrl + C` to copy all then paste it into the question without these artifacts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to speed up master.scene.\_render\_pygame\_def\_update() time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75012958/how-to-speed-up-master-scene-render-pygame-def-update-time)