# how to speed up master.scene._render_pygame_def_update() time

Tags: python, math, 3d, projection

im trying to make a 3d renderer but i can only get at most 20fps on idle.
i tried using @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None) on project_and_rotate() and got it up to 40fps on idle.
is there any way i could make this any faster
im using a long math formula i found a few month ago but it seems to be to slow for the map in projected_des

```
from math import *
import pygame
import numpy
from functools import lru_cache





@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def project_and_rotate(x, y, z,rotx,roty,rotz,posx,posy,posz,cx,cy,cz,scale,render_distance):
            x,y,z=x-posx,y-posy,z-posz
            if abs(x)>render_distance or abs(z)>render_distance:return None
            
            px = (((x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * cos(roty) - z * sin(roty)) * (315 / ((((z * cos(roty) + (x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * sin(roty)) * cos(rotx) + (y * cos(rotz) + x * sin(rotz)) * sin(rotx)) + 5) + cz))) * scale + cx
            py = (((y * cos(rotz) + x * sin(rotz)) * cos(rotx) - (z * cos(roty) + (x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * sin(roty)) * sin(rotx)) * (315 / ((((z * cos(roty) + (x * cos(rotz) - sin(rotz) * y) * sin(roty)) * cos(rotx) + (y * cos(rotz) + x * sin(rotz)) * sin(rotx)) + 5) + cz))) * scale + cy
            
            return [round(px),round(py)]




    
class coordinate:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z
        
class verticies_structure:
    def __init__(self):
        self._verts=[]
    def add_vert(self,x,y,z):
        self._verts.append(coordinate(x,y,z))
    def get_coords(self,indexes):
        return self._verts[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]
        
class camera:
    def __init__(self,w,h,render_distance,fov=45):
        self.fov=360-fov
        self.w=w
        self.h=h
        self.x=0
        self.rx=0
        self.cx=0
        self.y=0
        self.ry=0
        self.cy=0
        self.z=0
        self.rz=0
        self.cz=0
        self.render_distance=render_distance
        
def false(f,value):
    if value==f:
        value=f+0.01
    return value
    
def inf360(value):
    if value>359:value=0
    if value<0:value=359
    return value
        
        
class mesh(object):
    def __init__(self,file_obj,cam):
        self.cam=cam
        self.verts=verticies_structure()
        self.source=file_obj
        self.read_object_file()
        
        self.verts=verticies_structure()
        
        size=100
        for x in range(size):
            for z in range(size):
                self.verts.add_vert(x-size//2,0,z-size//2)
        
        
        self.w2s_vect=numpy.vectorize(self.w2s)
        self.array_verts=numpy.array(self.verts._verts)
                
                
    def w2s(self,coord):
        cam=self.cam
        return project_and_rotate(coord.x,coord.y,coord.z,cam.ry,cam.rx,cam.rz,cam.x,cam.y,cam.z,cam.cx,cam.cy,cam.cz,10,cam.render_distance)
        


        
    def projected_des(self,cam):
        #return self.w2s_vect(self.array_verts).tolist()
            
        return map( lambda coord:project_and_rotate(coord.x,coord.y,coord.z,cam.ry,cam.rx,cam.rz,cam.x,cam.y,cam.z,cam.cx,cam.cy,cam.cz,10,cam.render_distance),self.verts.get_coords([0,-1]))    
        
    def read_object_file(self):
        self.verts=verticies_structure()        
        import re
        reComp = re.compile("(?<=^)(v |vn |vt |f )(.*)(?=$)", re.MULTILINE)
        with open(self.source) as f:
            data = [txt.group() for txt in reComp.finditer(f.read())]
        v_arr, vn_arr, vt_arr, f_arr = [], [], [], []
        for line in data:
            tokens = line.split(' ')
            if tokens[0] == 'v':
                v_arr.append([float(c) for c in tokens[1:]])
            elif tokens[0] == 'vn':
                vn_arr.append([float(c) for c in tokens[1:]])
            elif tokens[0] == 'vt':
                vn_arr.append([float(c) for c in tokens[1:]])
            elif tokens[0] == 'f':
                f_arr.append([[int(i) if len(i) else 0 for i in c.split('/')] for c in tokens[1:]])
        vertices, normals = [], []
        for face in f_arr:
            for tp in face:
                self.verts.add_vert(*v_arr[tp[0]-1])
        
        self.array_verts=numpy.array(self.verts._verts)
class draw:
    class frame:
        class pygame_uitl:
            def grid(rowx,rowy,px,color=(255,255,255)):
                display=pygame.display.get_surface()
                for r in range(rowx):
                    r+=1
                    pygame.draw.line(display,color,(0,(display.get_height()/(rowx+1))*r),(display.get_width(),(display.get_height()/(rowx+1))*r),px)
                for r in range(rowy):
                    r+=1
                    pygame.draw.line(display,color,((display.get_width()/(rowy+1))*r,0),((display.get_width()/(rowy+1))*r,display.get_height()),px)
  

class system:                    
    class pygame_util:
        def get_orientation():
            inf=pygame.display.Info()
            w,h=inf.current_w,inf.current_h
            if w>h:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0




class Drivers:
    class Pygame:
        DEFAULT="PG-default"
        SDL2="PG-sdl2"
    
class master:
    class scene:
        def __init__(self,wh:list,display_driver:str,render_distance:int,fps:int):
            self._model={
                "class 1":[],
                "class 2":[],
                "class 3":[],
                "class 4":[]}
            self._fps=fps
            self._window_wh=wh
            self._driver=display_driver
            self._camera=camera(*wh,render_distance)
            self._mode="mesh"
            self._super_ls=0
            
            if display_driver==Drivers.Pygame.DEFAULT:
                self._render_pygame_def_setup()
            
        def add_model(self,file):
            model=mesh(file,self._camera)
            vertexes=len(model.verts._verts)
            if vertexes>100:
                self._model["class 4"].append(model)
            elif vertexes>50:
                self._model["class 3"].append(model)
            elif vertexes>25:
                self._model["class 2"].append(model)
            else:
                self._model["class 1"].append(model)
        def regulate_camera(self):
            self._camera.rx,self._camera.ry,self._camera.rz=false(0,self._camera.rx),false(0,self._camera.ry),false(0,self._camera.rz)
            self._camera.cx,self._camera.cy,self._camera.cz=false(0,self._camera.cx),false(0,self._camera.cy),false(0,self._camera.cz)  
        def correct_camera(self,orient=1):
            self._orient=orient
            if orient:
                self._camera.cx=self._window_wh[1]//2
                self._camera.cy=self._window_wh[0]
                self._camera.ry=0.4
            else:
                self._camera.cx=self._window_wh[0]//2
                self._camera.cy=self._window_wh[1]
                self._camera.ry=0.2
                
        def auto_render_distance(self):
            if self._driver==Drivers.Pygame.DEFAULT:
                if self._pygame_clock.get_fps()+5>self._fps:
                    self._camera.render_distance+=1
                else:
                    self._camera.render_distance-=1

        def landscape_super(self):
            self._super_ls=1
            self._lss_hdri_file_jpg_surf=pygame.Surface([self._window_wh[0],self._window_wh[1]//2.01])
            self._lss_hdri_file_jpg_surf.fill((200,220,255))
            
        def _render_pygame_def_setup(self):
            self._pygame_clock=pygame.time.Clock()
            self._pygame_screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self._camera.w,self._camera.h),pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.HWACCEL|pygame.HWSURFACE)
            
        def _render_pygame_def_update(self):
                self._pygame_screen.fill((0,70,0))
                self.regulate_camera()

                for idx,vclass in self._model.items():
                    for model in vclass: 
                        for point in model.projected_des(self._camera):
                            if point!=None:
                                try:self._pygame_screen.set_at(point,(255,255,255))
                                except:pass



                
                if self._super_ls:
                    self._pygame_screen.blit(self._lss_hdri_file_jpg_surf,(0,0))     
        
        def _render_pygame_def_finish(self):
                pygame.display.flip()
                self._pygame_clock.tick(self._fps)
                
                










   
                
scene=master.scene([2176,1080],Drivers.Pygame.DEFAULT,render_distance=25,fps=60)

scene.add_model("cube.obj")
scene.correct_camera(0)
scene.landscape_super()


#make the sky mapped to edge of render
pygame.font.init()
while 1:
    rx,ry=pygame.mouse.get_rel()
    scene._camera.rx+=rx/200
    
    scene._render_pygame_def_update()
    
    #scene.auto_render_distance()
    
    scene._pygame_screen.blit(pygame.font.SysFont(None,60).render(str(scene._pygame_clock.get_fps()),None,(255,0,0)),(0,0))
    
    scene._render_pygame_def_finish()
```

Comment: Is there a way to simplify the equation? Besides that you reuse various methods in the equation are there ways that you could save those values before using them in the final equation?

Comment: Have you run a profiler to see where your code is taking the most time -- so that you can adequately address areas that need improvement

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would reduce the number of math expressions in project_and_rotate

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def project_and_rotate(x, y, z,rotx,roty,rotz,posx,posy,posz,cx,cy,cz,scale,render_distance):
    x,y,z=x-posx,y-posy,z-posz
    if abs(x)>render_distance or abs(z)>render_distance:
        return None
    
    cos_rotz = cos(rotz)
    sin_rotz = sin(rotz)
    cos_roty = cos(roty)
    sin_roty = sin(roty)
    cos_rotx = cos(rotx)
    sin_rotx = sin(rotx)
    
    intermediate_1 = (x * cos_rotz - sin_rotz * y)
    intermediate_2 = (z * cos_roty + intermediate_1 * sin_roty)
    intermediate_3 = (y * cos_rotz + x * sin_rotz) * sin_rotx)
    intermediate_4 = (315 / (((intermediate_2 * cos_rotx + intermediate_3 + 5) + cz))) * scale
    
    px = ((intermediate_1 * cos_roty - z * sin_roty) * intermediate_4 + cx
    py = (((y * cos_rotz + x * sin_rotz) * cos_rotx - intermediate_2 * sin_rotx) * intermediate_4 + cy
    
    return [round(px), round(py)]
```

However, to fully improve your script -- it would be wise to profile the code to see where the script is taking the most time.

For a better discussion you should see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/